# Python 2.7: Trouble fitting a Poisson distributed histogram; curve drops off quickly

Tags: python

I have a discrete set of data which looks Poisson distributed between 0 and 90. I'm trying to curve fit the data. My code is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import poisson
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.misc import factorial

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))

entries, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(data, bins = 90, range = [1, 90], normed = True)
bin_middles = 0.5*(bin_edges[1:] + bin_edges[:-1])

def poisson(k, lamb):
    return (lamb**k/factorial(k)) * np.exp(-lamb)

params, cov = curve_fit(poisson, bin_middles, entries)
x_plot = np.linspace(1, 90, 90)

plt.plot(x_plot, poisson(x_plot, *params), 'b--', lw = 2)
plt.axvline(np.mean(data), linestyle = '--', color = 'g')
plt.ylim(0, max(entries)+max(entries)/4)
plt.xlim([0, max(x_plot)])
```

[image]

I can't identify why the curve is sitting to the left and the values are extremely small. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you provide the data, or put some synthetic data in so I could play with it?

Comment: Or better yet, a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but I can't get the picture into the comments. I'm getting a nice fit on some synthetic data with your code (added proper imports):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.misc import factorial
%matplotlib inline

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))

#make up some synthetic data
data = np.random.poisson(3, 5000000)

entries, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(data, bins = 90, range = [1, 90], normed = True)
bin_middles = 0.5*(bin_edges[1:] + bin_edges[:-1])

def poisson(k, lamb):
    return (lamb**k/ factorial(k)) * np.exp(-lamb)

params, cov =  curve_fit(poisson, bin_middles, entries)

x_plot = np.linspace(1, 30, 30)

plt.plot(x_plot, poisson(x_plot, *params), 'r', lw = 2)
```

[image]

Your data are definitely not very Poissonian (relationship between peak and width is wrong, plus the very slow dropoff to the right), but I can't find the reason why your plot is so far off, either.

Comment: I think you're right. The distribution is too skewed to be Poisson, and I'm wondering if that's what is affecting the fit. I can't share the data unfortunately (it's proprietary), but your synthetic data has convinced me that my problem is a data issue and not a coding one. Thanks!